# Why does Make use ASFLAGS for both gcc and as when their flags aren't compatible?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to assemble and link some code for a 32-bit target from a 64-bit host, and I'm trying to use `make`'s implicit rules as much as possible.

If I put `-m32` in `ASFLAGS` it works fine for linking and assembling in one step, as `make` will use `gcc` for this. But if one of my executables needs separate linking, everything breaks, because `make` will then use `as` for assembling, and `as` doesn't understand `-m32`. To solve this I can use `--32` instead, but this will of course not work with `gcc`.

```
$ cat Makefile
ASFLAGS = -m32

all: prog1 prog2

prog2: prog2.o

$ make
cc -m32   prog1.s   -o prog1
as -m32  -o prog2.o prog2.s
as: unrecognized option '-m32'
<builtin>: recipe for target 'prog2.o' failed
make: *** [prog2.o] Error 1
```

Why does `make` use `ASFLAGS` for both `gcc` and `as` when their flags aren't compatible? Am I not supposed to specify the architecture this way? Do I really have to hack my way around this (i.e. actually write something in my Makefile), or is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ASFLAGS is used by both LINK.s (gcc) and COMPILE.s (as) as you mentioned, one possible solution is to add following in the Makefile for compiling %.s with $(AS),

```
EXTRA_ASFLAGS = --32
%.o : %.s
        $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) $(EXTRA_ASFLAGS) $(TARGET_MACH) -o $@ $<
```

, or

```
COMPILE.s += --32
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying to avoid doing the first thing, but I hadn't thought of the second. `COMPILE.s += --32` and `LDFLAGS = -m32` works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you lied to `make` and `as`. If you put in `ASFLAGS` something that is not an assembler option, you're doing something out of spec.

`make` cannot know what options the compiler and assembler understand. To deal with this, `make` provides a way to specify the options for each tool separately: use `CFLAGS` for the compiler, `ASFLAGS` for the assembler, `LDFLAGS` for the link step.

I suggest using `make CFLAGS=-m32 ASFLAGS=--32`.

Comment: That doesn't work because `ASFLAGS`, not`CFLAGS`, is included in the default rule for assembling and linking `%.s`-files with `gcc`.

Comment: @R.Mitchum Hm. ASFLAGS is not POSIX, so it's hard to say how it should be used in default rules. Anyway, does using `.POSIX:` as the first line of your GNUmakefile make a difference?

Comment: It changes `cc` to `c99`, but that doesn't change the interpretation of the flags.